# can resourceHandler and resourceLocation be same

Tags: spring-mvc

Why this doesnt work ?`registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");`

but This works

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note the **addResourceHandler(String... pathPatterns)** accepts any of your preferred URL path patterns you are going to use in your pages and it then creates a resource handler for serving static resources based on your URL patterns. In your **addResourceLocations** you then need to specify the specific location of your resources.

> So when you change your URL pattern in your resource handler make sure
>   to apply the same changes in your pages and templates so that static
>   resources can be picked. The below examples can help you to understand
>   how the resource handler works.

Example 1 : In your case you have :

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

in your page you can then use :

```
<link href="resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Example 2 : In your case you have :

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

in your page you can then use :

```
<link href="res/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Example 3 : In your case you have :

```
registry.addResourceHandler("*.css").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");
```

in your page you can then use :

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: I already tried the same as you pointed out in example 2 . but its not working. secondly I want /apps/** to point to /angularApps/ and /js/** to point to /resources/js/ and /css/** to point to /resources/css/ . any other hints?

Comment: I guess your static resources are as follows: **src\main\webapp\resources**, and **src\main\webapp\angularApps**. If so then CSS example:  /css/** should have the config like 'registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");' Then link : '<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>'. Also, do you have spring security enabled in your app? If so you then need to permit all resource URL patterns using permitAll on such resource url patterns.